# How can one detect programmatically that his code is running on Google Cloud?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm trying to adapt my Spark jobs that are currently running on an on-premise Hadoop cluster. I want to modify it so that it keeps supporting run on-premise and run on Google cloud.

I was thinking to have a method to detect if a given environment variable is defined to determine if the code is running in the cloud:

```
def run_on_gcp():
  return is_defined(os.env["ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE"])
```

I wanted to know what would be an `ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE` that is always defined on Google cloud and that is accessible from a Dataproc instance? 
I was thinking of `PROJECT_ID` OR `BUCKET`, which such variable do you usually use? How do you usually detect programmatically where your code is running? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose you can use `DATAPROC_VERSION`. If you [submit](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/submit-job#submitting_a_job) the following PySpark job to Dataproc it will print out the version you are using (1.3 in my case):

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import pyspark, os
sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
print(os.getenv("DATAPROC_VERSION"))
```

Answer (score 1):

When you submit job to dataproc, you can assign your args. such as profile name, cluster name.

```
CMD="--job mytestJob \
 --job-args path=gs://tests/report\
   profile=gcp \
   cluster_name=${GCS_CLUSTER}"


gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark \
    --cluster ${GCS_CLUSTER} \
    --py-files ${PY_FILES} \
    --async \
    ${PY_MAIN} \
    -- ${CMD}
```

Then you can dectect those args in your program .

```
  environment = {
      'PYSPARK_JOB_ARGS': ' '.join(args.job_args) if args.job_args else ''
  }

  job_args = dict()
  if args.job_args:
      job_args_tuples = [arg_str.split('=') for arg_str in args.job_args]
      print('job_args_tuples: %s' % job_args_tuples)
      job_args = {a[0]: a[1] for a in job_args_tuples}

  print('\nRunning job %s ...\n environment is %s\n' % (args.job_name, environment))

  os.environ.update(environment)
```